# How to remove all apps from Dock on Sonoma?

Tags: mac, dock, sonoma

I started a new job and my work computer is a new MacBook running Sonoma. There are about 20 apps preloaded into the Dock that I will never use for work (iTunes, Apple TV, and so on). Is there a way to clear the dock completely and start over, or must I remove apps one by one by right clicking them and selecting Remove from Dock?

I looked at the Dock preferences in System Settings, and googled to no avail.

Comment: As far as I can determine [with under 100% certainty, hence not posting this as an answer] the Dock information is stored in an SQL database at `~/Library/Application Support/Dock/` This is not something for the uninitiated to play in. It will take you 30 seconds to right click>Options or just drag all the items you don't want in the Dock out to the desktop, which will also remove them.

Comment: Note: If your laptop is under the aegis of your company's MDM, either you may not be able to remove items from the Dock, or they may reappear after the next login. That being said, the manual removal process doesn't take very long.

Comment: Wow...  sounds like a tough job.